# Replace plywood sheathing under metal roof

Tags: roof, roofing, sheathing

I have a metal roof with exposed fasteners, and I have some mold in the attic on my plywood roof sheathing.  The source of the moisture that caused the mold is already fixed.  My mold inspector says it would be best to replace the sheathing rather than remediating it in place.  It isn't possible to replace the sheathing without taking the roof off.  The roof exterior isn't very old, and it's still in pretty good shape.

Is it possible to take the metal roof off, replace the sheathing, and then put the original metal roof back on?  Is this something that has been done before?  Would I create leaks?  Is this really dumb?

The other option is to put on a brand new roof + sheathing, but it seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: A few pictures of the area would be helpful.

Comment: I would take off all the roof metal and the problematic sheathing so that you can properly remediate and install a quality new roof that you can trust to last a long time. Last thing you need is to compromise the roof in any way and then coming back in a year or two to have to repair some leaks. The material you remove from the roof can very well see a new life as the sidewall covering for a future outbuilding shed or sold to someone else that can use it for that purpose.

Comment: Without a photo we really can’t see how bad the mold is. All plywood is loaded with mold spores, I worked at a plywood mill and the veneer stacks would regularly turn colors from all the fungi growing on the edge of the stacks. If the wood was not damaged I would use hydrogen peroxide at least 3% to kill the surface mold. It can be sponged on or even a paint roller to apply (at 3% I have used a spray bottle but not with stronger concentrations) with out a photo we can’t say it would be foolish or prudent to replace the sheeting. Keeping it dry after treatment will be important.